# Python Kafka producer unable to write to topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kerberos, producer

I am using python kafka producer to write to a topic. The Kafka server is external and I connecting with credentials using Kerberos. When I run the producer script, it seems like connection is being established to server but for some reason, the metadata request fails with 'Request 1: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=NULL)'.

Here is the producer code:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

broker = ['mybroker.com:9092']

p = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=broker,security_protocol='SSL',ssl_cafile="truststore.pem",ssl_keyfile='truststore.jks',sasl_mechanism='GSSAPI',api_version=(0, 10, 1))
topic = 'test-topic'
# Write hello world to test topic
p.send(topic, bytes("Hello World", 'utf-8'))
p.flush()
```

Here is the error I am currently getting:

```
EBUG:kafka.producer.kafka:Starting the Kafka producer
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name connections-closed
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name connections-created
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name select-time
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name io-time
INFO:kafka.client:Bootstrapping cluster metadata from [('fakehost.lef.ceg.com', 9092, <AddressFamily.AF_UNSPEC: 0>)]
DEBUG:kafka.client:Attempting to bootstrap via node at mybroker.com:9092
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name bytes-sent-received
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name bytes-sent
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name bytes-received
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name request-latency
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name node-bootstrap.bytes-sent
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name node-bootstrap.bytes-received
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name node-bootstrap.latency
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)=9092>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)/iphere port=9092>: configuring default SSL Context
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)/iphere port=9092>: Loading SSL CA from /truststore.pem
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)/iphere port=9092>: wrapping socket in ssl context
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)/iphere port=9092>: connecting to iphere
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)/iphere port=9092>: established TCP connection
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)/iphere port=9092>: initiating SSL handshake
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)/iphere port=9092>: completed SSL handshake.
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)/iphere port=9092>: Connection complete.
DEBUG:kafka.client:Node bootstrap connected
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)/iphere port=9092> Request 1: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=NULL)
ERROR:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)/iphere port=9092>: socket disconnected
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)/iphere port=9092>: Closing connection. ConnectionError: socket disconnected
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap host=:)/iphere port=9092>: reconnect backoff 0.04487732169774206 after 1 failures
ERROR:kafka.client:Unable to bootstrap from [('mybroker.com', 9092, <AddressFamily.AF_UNSPEC: 0>)]
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name bufferpool-wait-time
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name batch-size
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name compression-rate
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name queue-time
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name produce-throttle-time
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name records-per-request
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name bytes
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name record-retries
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name errors
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name record-size-max
DEBUG:kafka.producer.sender:Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.producer.kafka:Kafka producer started
DEBUG:kafka.producer.kafka:Requesting metadata update for topic test-topic
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
```

What does this actually mean and how do I go about debugging this ?

Comment: Hi, are you able to produce a test record using a kafka-console-producer, using the bootstrap-server you used in your python script ( maybe something wrong with Kafka your cluster ). Could you check the Kafka logs as well ?

Comment: I just tried the kafka-console-producer, thank you for your suggestion. I did 

bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list mybroker.com:9092 security.protocol=SSL \ ssl.key.location=truststore.jks \ ssl.certificate.location=./truststore.pem --topic "test-topic"

I get the following error:

[2020-03-14 00:02:37,584] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker mybroker.com:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Comment: There is no broker running at `mybroker.com:9092`, perhaps

Comment: You can't set security protocol on the CLI like that. You need to use a config file. Also, python needs certificates as well

Comment: There's something wrong with your configuration. You set the `security_protocol` to `SSL` but you also set `sasl_mechanism='GSSAPI'`. Do you want to use SASL or only SSL?

Comment: @MickaelMaison I want to use SASL_SSL. Also, how can I set a config file? Thanks.

Comment: Then you need to set `security_protocol` to `SASL_SSL`. ALso SASL requires a few more settings, see http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl for example for each mechanism. Finally with the console tools, you need to set settings in a config file, this is described in http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_configclients

Comment: @MickaelMaison When I set the security_protocol to SASL_SSL, I get the following error:  Invalid token was supplied, Minor (100001) Error invalid token received from server

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to initiate producer using python

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import time
import json

topic = 'testing'
bootstrap_servers = '<your broker>:9092'
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers)
msg=json.dumps({"status":True})  # update your message here
future = producer.send(topic, msg.encode('utf-8'))
result = future.get(timeout=60)
metrics = producer.metrics()
print(metrics)
```

Message format is independent, you can use any format to send the messages